# ACL / RBAC implementation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, acl, rbac

I'm coding a website similar to a forum. There are Posts that any user can make, only the poster can edit their post, but moderators can edit *any* post, and admins can alter user's privileges to promote them to Mod/Admin, as well as alter board settings, etc.

So here we've set the stage for (as far as I understand it) ACL where the posts can be altered by their owner **and** RBAC where users can have roles to give them access to resources regardless of their individual requirements.

I'm wondering about how to lay this out in my SQL tables.

I would have thought to do it like so:

Tables:

- Users -- ID / Name / (etc)
- Users_Groups -- UserID / GroupID
- Groups -- ID / Name / IsAdmin / CanEditOtherPosts / CanDoOtherStuff /
  Etc
- Post -- ID / Content / Owner / (etc..)

And so upon editing a post I would check if the user is the post's owner, or if has the 'CanEditOtherPosts' option set true.

I know this implementation would work just fine, I decided to check phpBB's and Wordpress's MySQL structure before actually doing this. I have now become a little concerned.

I've noticed that in phpBB / Wordpress rather than naming their permissions in the Column name they have the following:

- Users -- ID / Name / (etc)
- Users_Groups -- UserID / GroupID
- Groups -- ID / Name
- Permissions -- ID / Name
- Groups_Permissions -- ID / GroupID / PermissionID / Value

This seems a lot more robust than my original solution. Making it so if I need to add a different permission later I don't have to add a column to the table. (which isn't **too** hard) Though is there any other reason why I should use this method over mine? Would this method have any performance gains/hits? (probably negligible?)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. My motto when creating this website is 'Do it right, the first time' Rewriting something that already works for a performance gain or to get over a limitation is something that I want to avoid. I'd rather spend more time in the design stage.

Comment: Personally I would make `groups` as `(id, name, short_name)`. You can then internally decode short_name to mean whatever you want, and you don't have to modify the database to add a new permission.

Comment: Your coding motto is flawed, IMO - it is a recipe for so much precision that your first release never makes it to market. "Do it quickly, get it into production, listen to your users and iterate from there" is probably a better one.

Comment: @halfer - That seems to be the most logical route and will make future coding and modifications easier. I am wondering if there is a best practices model or advice on this subject.
and yes, I realize the flaw in my motto, I understand and somewhat agree with the 'get it working, get it done, improve from there' idea aswell. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I'd say pick my one or the WordPress one, and implement it. If it needs to change in the future, so be it. In most cases, worries about performance are premature or never materialise. Get it done `:)`